# View PCA component matrix in R

Tags: r, pca

I am using R for a PCA, using the function `princomp` (I'm also open to using `prcomp`). I'd like to view the component matrix, as found in SPSS, where each variable is correlated to each component.

Note this is different to the loadings which `princomp` can return for you.

Can I call it directly from my `princomp` output, or is there a hacky way I can generate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For princomp

```
data(iris)
pc <- princomp(iris[,1:3)
pc$loadings
```

you can looking at str(pc) so see all the elements of the object generated by princomp.

For prcomp I think the equivalent is

```
pc <- prcomp(iris[,1:3])
pc$rotation
```

Comment: As far as I understand, loadings are different to the correlations I'm looking for. Loadings relate to the eigenvalue of each variable for that specific component, whereas I'm looking for the correlation matrix for variables and components (i.e. how well the variation in a variable describes the variation in the component).